# Updating columns in php ?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I apologise if I’m asking this question wrong I’m new to stackoverflow and to php.

I'm trying to update my database with new values being a title and contents. Each row has a ID. I want to update the info at only that ID row. This is the statement that i'm using. Which isnt working could anyone offer me some advice please ?`

```
  $updateBlog = $c->query("UPDATE blog SET ( title, content) VALUES ('$updateTitle', $postContent ) WHERE id = $updateID");
```

Comment: As `$postContent` is likely a string, it needs to be quoted in your SQL

Comment: Your `UPDATE` syntax is *all* wrong. Looks like you're trying to do an `INSERT` instead.

Comment: Better yet, learn to use prepared statements/bind variables using MySQLi or PDO.... it is 2016 now, after all, so why inject data values directly into your SQL statements and have to remember to escape values and all the other overheads that entails

Comment: `UPDATE blog SET title='My Title', content= 'My content' WHERE id=1` =>`UPDATE blog SET title=?, content= ? WHERE id=?`

Comment: When you get something that `isnt working` you should try to get an error out of it so you have something to work with, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: Many thanks for all of your feedback I really appreciate it, I will look into PDO. Again i'm just getting used to the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query syntax is not right for an `UPDATE` and you'rre missing the quotes around your second variable:

```
UPDATE blog 
SET title = '$updateTitle',
content = '$postContent'
WHERE id = $updateID
```

This will make your statement look like this:

```
$updateBlog = $c->query("UPDATE blog SET title = '$updateTitle', content = '$postContent' WHERE id = $updateID);
```

Leaving your query like this [opens you to risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) You really should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank You very much worked. I will research SQL injections

Answer (score -1):

```
  $updateBlog = $c->query("UPDATE blog SET ( title, content) VALUES ('{$updateTitle}', {$postContent} ) WHERE id = {$updateID}");
```

You should REALLY look into some input validation and cleaning for your values though. If this is coming straight from a user input it's highly susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: ahh, i didn't even look at the sql. I thought it was an interpolation issue.

Comment: Thank you very much will look into validation